# Measure power with multiple measurements

Tags: power, rms

I want to measure the mean power draw of a Jetson Nano. I did this by using a digital multimeter and running the measurement 60 times with a fixed integration time of 0.3s.

The result of each measurement is:

$$U_{rms}, I_{rms}$$

To calculate the power I am taking the average of RMS values.

$$P=\bar{U}_{rms}*\bar{I}_{rms}$$

Is the power P now just the mean power draw as of \$\bar{P}\$ or how would I have to define P?

Edit:
I am trying to clarify what I am trying to achieve. First of all the my end goal is to get a value for \$\bar{W}/frame\$. Because the inference time on the Jetson nano is not consistent I am overshooting with my integration time to fully cover the measurement and to balance that out I am subtracting the idle energy after wards. The reason I am measuring with RMS is that, only after about half the measurement the power draw increases again so I need the total energy draw in the time period. Now because the inference times vary a bit I want to take the mean of that and thus the mean \$\bar{W}/frame\$.
$$W=U*I*t$$
[image]

Comment: That's apparent power. Not real power. Apparent power is the the power max real power you can get from a given U and I. That happens when the power factor is 1 which is th same thing as saying that the phase shift between U and I is zero which is the same thing as saying that data point of U and I have the same polarity.

Comment: Also, you can't average RMS values. At least, you can't average them like a normal average. Taking an average of RMS values is kind of like taking an average of a bunch of average values: not necessarily valid. You would be safer calculating the power from each U and I sample you took and then averaging the power.

Comment: Apparent Power equals real power for DC circuits doesn't it?

How do I need to average them?

Comment: Oh yes, I guess you did say Jetson Nano so yeah that would be all DC.

Comment: How should I process my 60 measurements than ?

Comment: What is the sampling frequency of the DMM during the integration time? Is it capable of capturing the current variations?

Comment: The sampling rate is 10kSa/s, so its should be capable and I cant rerun the measurements because I got no time for that..

Answer (score 2):

It is incorrect to multiply the RMS values.

If the V is constant, then there is no need to use its RMS value --and for small amounts of ripple, then a straightforward average is OK.

Given that V is nearly constant, there is no need to use an RMS value for current -- also use an average.

So your avg_power calculation can be V_avg*I_avg, *assuming* that V has negligible ripple on it. If the ripple is 'large' then your calculation should be avg_power = avg(V*I) -- you have to do the multiplication before averaging. You cannot use individual RMS values for V and I easily unless you know the phase difference between them (and are dealing with sinusoids).

RMS does work for just measuring resistive loss due to current -- because the current and voltage are in phase, so avg(V*I) = avg(I*R *I) = avg(I²*R) == RMS(current).

Comment: I edited the post. I am only measuring DC currents, but I tried to explain why I need the RMS.

Comment: @HWilmer assuming the screen you posted is from an oscilloscope measuring both current and voltage and capable of saving CSV files, you are much better off using this feature to calculate instantaneous power exactly in the period you want.

Comment: This might be better, but I made around 1600 measurements. So its not feasible to all calculate them with a scope the CSV files of the scope. Also I already did the measurements and I cant redo them, but my questions remains. Is it wrong to take the avg(U_rms) ?

Comment: Yes, avg(U_rms) is wrong, but not significantly (assuming your meter is DC coupled and included the DCcomponent). It is very wrong to use avg(I_rms) -- best to use avg(I).